# web application runs much faster in embedded tomcat than in standalone tomcat

Tags: spring, performance, tomcat

I have a spring-boot web application (mostly used through REST calls), that I can run using `mvn exec` that starts an embedded tomcat (8.5.11), or build a war and deploy it into a standalone tomcat (debian stock 8.5.14-1~bpo8+1). Both are configured the same way, using

To our utmost surprise, the embedded tomcat seems to be much faster for high loads (a small test sequence with 200+ threads using jmeter). At 600 threads, for example:

- The standalone tomcat has very large response times, while having a relatively low load of 50-70 (the server has 64 cores and can run 128 threads), and a low IO usage.
- The embedded tomcat has a load of 150-200 and faster response times, and high I/O usage (it seems that the database is the limiting factor here, but it degrades gracefully: 600 threads results in double as slow as 300 threads).

Supposedly, the configuration is the same for both tomcats, so currently I am quite troubled because of this. I really would not like to run embedded tomcat in production if I can help it.

Does anyone have an idea:

- what the cause for this performance disparity may be, and
- how we can reliably compare the configuration for two tomcats?

**Update**

I ran some more tests and discovered a significant difference after looking through the Garbage Collector logs: with 600 jmeter threads, the embedded tomcat spent about 5% of its time GCing, while the standalone tomcat spent about 50% of its time GCing. I calculated these numbers with an awk script, so they may be a bit mis-parsed, but manually checking the GC logs seems to corroborate them. It still does not explain *why* one of them is GCing all the time and the other is not...

**One more update**

I managed to speed up the standalone tomcat by switching the garbage collector to G1. Now, it uses about 20% of elapsed time for garbage collection, and never exceeds 1s for any single GC run. Now the standalone tomcat is only 20-30% slower than the embedded tomcat. Interestingly, using G1 in the embedded tomcat had no real effect on its performance, GC overhead is still around 15% there.

This is by no means a solution, but it helped to close the gap between the two tomcats and thus now the problem is not so critical.

Comment: I think you should research it further. There is a lot of info you can easily find on the pros and cons of embedded tomcat. You should really consider it for production.

Comment: Start by comparing server.xml files and JVM options (they should be in setenv.sh but they can be elsewhere)

Comment: @EugèneAdell There is no server.xml for the embedded tomcat, it is configured by spring-boot. I have configured thread and connection count the same, but I cannot say that they are really the same, as I have no way to query that information online :) .

Comment: @P.Péter is JMX activated ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the memory parameters for your standalone Tomcat and your spring boot application, especially the java heap size.

My guess is that your standalone Tomcat has a value for Xmx set in the startup script (catalina.sh and/or setenv.sh), say for example 1 Gb, which is much lower than what your Spring Boot app is using.

If you haven't specified a value for Xmx on the command line for your spring boot app, it will default to 25% of your physical memory. If your server has 16 Gb of RAM, that'll be 4Gb...

I'd recommend running your tests again after making sure the same JVM parameters are in use (Xms, Xmx, various GC options, ...). If unsure, inspect the running VMs with jVisualVm or similar tool.

Comment: Java heap size is set explicitly the same for both (32g). I will try to raise it for the standalone tomcat, as maybe it reserves some memory for himself unlike the embedded one

Comment: If I give the standalone tomcat 64g heap, the GC percentage goes down to 45%. It is not a big improvement, and this may just be a measurement error. :(

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the used heap using jVisualVm ? Are you hitting this 32Gb heap limit with both embedded and standalone tomcat ?

Comment: I did not use jVisualVm, but I do have a status page that displays current memory consumption. That shows that even 60g is filled in about 5 minutes under load by the standalone tomcat, and about the same is true for the embedded tomcat. Of course the GC frees that up regularly, but the embedded tomcat uses far less time to do it.